# How to set image path coming from server in uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I am making an app in which i am getting data from server and in data image path is also coming but when i am setting image to my tableview cell app will become too much heavy may b i am not setting image properly below is my sample code thanx in advance :)

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *tableviewidentifier = @"cell";
    tablecellTableViewCell *cell= [self.activitiesTableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[tablecellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
    }if(indexPath.row == [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1){
        // [[cell textLabel] setText:@"Load more records"];
    }

    UILabel *valuedate = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:21];
    UILabel *msg = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:22];
    UILabel *date = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:23];
    UILabel *time = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:24];
    valuedate.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"offerTitle"];
    msg.text=@"How are you?";
    NSString *img=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"offerPhoto"];// here i am getting image path
     UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:img]]];
    cell.imageView.image=img1;// here i am setting image due to which app is so heavy and stuck


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of : NSString *img. Add one just as a reference, you can get that from NSLog.

Comment: check my answer i edited  ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this below code, hope this helps u .

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   __block  tablecellTableViewCell *cell= [self.activitiesTableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
   if(cell==nil)
   {
      cell = [[tablecellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
   }
   if(indexPath.row == [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1)
   {
      // [[cell textLabel] setText:@"Load more records"];
   }
   UILabel *valuedate = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:21];
   UILabel *msg = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:22];
   UILabel *date = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:23];
   UILabel *time = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:24];
   valuedate.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"offerTitle"];
   msg.text=@"How are you?";

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{     
   NSString *img=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"offerPhoto"];// here i am getting image path
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:img];
   NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

   dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ //in main thread update the image
    cell.imageView.image = image;
    cell.textLabel.text = @""; //add this update will reflect the changes 
    });
  });
 return cell;
}
```

**EDIT**
in order to reuse the downloaded image u can either save them on disk or just for save them some where for example in dictionary for temporary using

in below code i took one example dictionary, and strong the download images with row as key

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableDictionary *imagesDictionary; //lets declare a mutable dictionary to hold images 
}
```

in this method just initialise it

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // rest of your code
    //...........
    //
    imagesDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]; //initilise 
 }
```

in index this method just add the downloaded images to dictionary for corresponding row as key

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
     __block  tablecellTableViewCell *cell= [self.activitiesTableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
       cell = [[tablecellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
    }
   if(indexPath.row == [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1)
   {
      // [[cell textLabel] setText:@"Load more records"];
   }
   __block NSString *row = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]; //add this

   UILabel *valuedate = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:21];
   UILabel *msg = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:22];
   UILabel *date = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:23];
   UILabel *time = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:24];
   // valuedate.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"offerTitle"];
   msg.text=@"How are you?";
   if(![[imagesDictionary allKeys] containsObject:row]) //if image not found download and add it to dictionary
   {
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
       // NSString *img=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"offerPhoto"];// here i am getting image path
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:img];
        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ //in main thread update the image
             [imagesDictionary setObject:image forKey:row]; //sorry, while editing to your code i forgot to add this 
            cell.imageView.image = image;
            cell.textLabel.text = @""; //add this update will reflect the changes
             NSLog(@"loading and addig to dictionary");
        });
    });
  }
  else
  {
    cell.imageView.image = [imagesDictionary objectForKey:row];
    NSLog(@"retriving from dictioary");
  }
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66655/discussion-on-answer-by-shan-how-to-set-image-path-coming-from-server-in-uitable).

Answer (score 2):

Dont use `imageWithData:` for setting images. It is synchronous and will make your app run slow.

Instead of that Use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

You just need to do following things:

1. Dump SDWebImage folder into your project.
2. Import `UIImageView+WebCache.h`.
3. Set the image using: `sd_setImageWithURL:`

OR

by [GCD (Grand Central Dispatch) and sending asynchronous requests](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial). Code copied from [HERE](http://natashatherobot.com/ios-how-to-download-images-asynchronously-make-uitableview-scroll-fast/).

First implement following method.

```
- (void)downloadImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url completionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image))completionBlock
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               if ( !error )
                               {
                                    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                                    completionBlock(YES,image);
                                } else{
                                    completionBlock(NO,nil);
                                }
                           }];
}
```

and then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
[self downloadImageWithURL:your_url completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image) {
            if (succeeded) {
                // change the image in the cell
                cell.imageView.image = image;


            }
        }];
```

Comment: anyother option except this ?

Comment: [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) but I would suggest SDWebImage. It is widely used n easy to understand.

Comment: any other built in option??

Comment: very useful library indeed.. thnx

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are calling dataWithContentsOfURL: function which will make the app non responsive because you are calling it on main thread. To make it responsive you need to create a custom cell YourCell and declare a method in YourCell.h

```
@interface YourCell : UITableViewCell
{
    UIImage *_cImage;
}

- (void)downloadImageFromURL:(NSURL *)imageUrl;
@end
```

Now in YourCell.m you need to do like this:

```
- (void)downloadImageFromURL:(NSURL *)imageUrl
{
    if (_cImage != nil)
    {
        self.imageView.image = _cImage;
    }
    else
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        _cImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl]];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.imageView.image = _cImage;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Now from cellForRowAtIndexPath: you just need to call downloadImageFromURL: function of YourCell and pass the imageUrl to it and its the cell responsibility to download and show the image.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier= @"YourCell";
    YourCell *cell = (YourCell *)[self.activitiesTableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    // Set your UILabels as before.....

    NSString *imagePath=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"offerPhoto"];
    [cell downloadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imagePath]];

    return cell;        
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: will you please mention cell for row indexpath method as well ?

Comment: @MishalAwan function added to the post.

Comment: @MishalAwan vote up if you find the post useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageView *img1 = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:104];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            img1.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:img]]];
        });
    });
```

Send async requests for images. Doing this would not block your UI until the image gets loaded.

Comment: what is the purpose of this ?

Comment: The above code can be used for sending asynchronous requests unlike the code used by you which sends sync requests. Sending sync requests blocks the UI completely until the whole image is downloaded. Say, if your internet is slow, then whole ui gets loaded except the images if you use Async request.

Comment: and what is fromimage.image it id giving error in my side?